# what is the cache behaviour of the data set by upsertQueryData util of rtk query?

Tags: redux-toolkit, rtk-query

For example, if I have a GET all query, and I want to pre-populate the cache for GET ones like so:

```js
export const service = apiService.injectEndpoints({
    endpoints: (build) => ({
        getAll: build.query({
            query: ...,
            providesTags: ...,
            onQueryStarted: async (arg, api) => {
                try {
                    const result = await api.queryFulfilled;
                    result.data.items.forEach((item) => {
                        api.dispatch(staffService.util.upsertQueryData('getOne', { id: itemid }, item));
                    });
                } catch { }
            },
        }),
        getOne: build.query({
            query: ...,
            providesTags: ...,
        }),
    }),
})
```

when do the cache entries for `getOne` expire?